# get index and value of bubblesort python

Tags: python, bubble-sort, enumerate

I implemented a bubble sort for sorting a list of numbers, I tried to use enumerate to get the indices as well as the values, but for some reason in doesn't work. I expect something like [(index, value)], but the output can be different as well, as long I can see the index with the value part.
Result **[(4, 25), (2, 30), (3, 31), (1, 33), (0,38)].**
Hope there is a simple change for that.

```
def sortPercent(unsortedArr):
    n = len(unsortedArr)
    for i, percent in enumerate(range(n-1)):        
        for j, percent in enumerate(range(0, n-i-1)):        
            if unsortedArr[j] > unsortedArr[j + 1]:
                unsortedArr[j],unsortedArr[j+1] = unsortedArr[j+1], unsortedArr[j]
    return unsortedArr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unsortedArr = [38, 33, 30, 31, 25]
    print(sortPercent(unsortedArr))
```

Comment: you are using `enumerate` on `range()`

Comment: ok but without range I get the error, that int object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use enumerate on unsorted arr

```
def sortPercent(unsortedArr):
    unsortedArr = list(enumerate(unsortedArr)) # [(0, 38), (1, 33), (2, 30), (3, 31), (4, 25)]
    n = len(unsortedArr)
    for i, percent in enumerate(range(n-1)):        
        for j, percent in enumerate(range(0, n-i-1)):        
            if unsortedArr[j][1] > unsortedArr[j + 1][1]: # when j = 0, unsortedArr[j] = (0,38), unsortedArr[j][1] = 38, unsortedArr[j+1][1]=30
                unsortedArr[j],unsortedArr[j+1] = unsortedArr[j+1], unsortedArr[j]
    return unsortedArr


unsortedArr = [38, 33, 30, 31, 25]
print(sortPercent(unsortedArr))
# [(4, 25), (2, 30), (3, 31), (1, 33), (0, 38)]
```

Comment: wow super nice thanks, can you explain what the ```if unsortedArr[j][1] > unsortedArr[j + 1][1]:``` [1] are doing there?

Comment: when you enumerate it gives you  `[(0, value1), (1, value2) .... (N-1, valueN)]`.
I am using arr[1] to compare the value (e.g. value1),
edited the answer

Comment: The first part is clear, but I still don't get the second part with arr[1].

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `enumerate()` at all, this function definition does what you want, in simple code:

```py
def sortPercent(unsortedArr):
    n = len(unsortedArr)
    unsortedArr = [(i, unsortedArr[i]) for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n-1):        
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):        
            if unsortedArr[j][1] > unsortedArr[j + 1][1]:
                unsortedArr[j],unsortedArr[j+1] = unsortedArr[j+1], unsortedArr[j]
    return unsortedArr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sortPercent(unsortedArr):
    n = len(unsortedArr)

    for i, percent in enumerate(range(n-1)):        
        for j, percent in enumerate(range(0, n-i-1)):        
            if unsortedArr[j] > unsortedArr[j + 1]:
                unsortedArr[j],unsortedArr[j+1] = unsortedArr[j+1], unsortedArr[j]

    return unsortedArr

if __name__ == "__main__":

    unsortedArr = [38, 33, 30, 31, 25]

    sortedArr=sortPercent(unsortedArr.copy())
    for i in range (len(unsortedArr)):
         print(sortedArr[i],"-",unsortedArr.index(sortedArr[i]))
```